# Requiring jQuery at the global level for usage with Jquery UI modules

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, typescript, angular, webpack

I'm working on angular 2, in which I would like to require jQuery from Jquery ui. Each module adds itself to jQuery by accessing the global variable. I have spent hours searching pretty much every corner of Github and Stackoverflow (and other random websites) looking for solutions, but so far, not a single one has worked.

Methods I have tried:

ProvidePlugin for $, jQuery, and window.jQuery,
expose loader
imports loader 
various other combinations of requiring jQuery at different locations in my stack
I'm clearly missing something here. Every time I write import "jquery-ui"  , I get "jQuery is not defined

Thanks.

My webpack.config.js (for development)

```
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const DedupePlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');


var commonConfig = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // TypeScript
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['ts-loader'] },

      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style','css'] },
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        loader: 'html',
        query: {
          minimize: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: false,
          caseSensitive: true,
          // Teach html-minifier about Angular 2 syntax
          customAttrSurround: [
            [/#/, /(?:)/],
            [/\*/, /(?:)/],
            [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
          ],
          customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
        }
      },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['to-string', 'css', 'postcss', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap'] },
      { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' }
    ]
  },
  'uglify-loader': {
    mangle: false
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer];
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV)
    })
  ],
  devtool: process.env.ENV == 'dev'? 'source-map' : null
};

module.exports=commonConfig;
```

Comment: Kritika, without refering Jquery-UI.....is jquery part of page working ?

Comment: Kritika  i mean , are you using jquery other than Jquery UI in that page??

Comment: import {Component,OnInit,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import "jquery-ui";  yes I am importing jquery first and then jquery-ui

Comment: Yes jquery part is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to handle this :

1- Import jquery as an script inside you index.html .This should be straight forward.

2- Import it via webpack;

In your webpack common ;

```
alias: {
  "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
}
.
.
.
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    })
  , and the rest of you plugins 
 ]
```

In your typings :

1- Either download the source and put it in your folders somewhere

2- Or use the typings install to install it : here is the definition :

[Jquery Typings](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/jquery/jquery.d.ts)

Inside your app.ts ( the root component)

```
  declare var jQuery : JQueryStatic;
```

And have a look at my other to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605846/jquery-with-typescript-property-css-does-not-exist-on-type-elementfinder)

Comment: I want to do it by importing it through webpack.It doesn't work this way...already tried.

Comment: I did  typings install dt~jquery --global --save, typings install dt~jquery-ui --global --save and then they are added to index.d.ts file as well and jquery works just fine for me but jquery-ui is unable to find 'jQuery' variable

Comment: The webpack plugin does the job , that tells your jquery-ui that $ is equal to jQuery , make sure to use it